# Issue with drc package installation, error with drm

Tags: r

I'm hoping someone knows the answer to this issue. It's been previously brought up [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/problem-with-drc-package/12636https://) and was resolved, with the problem attributed to an antivirus preventing the installation. I don't currently have an antivirus installed on my mac, but it still seems to be an issue. Here is the code input:

```
> snailcloth7x<-drm(mort/total~conc, weights=total, data=snailcloth7, fct=LL.4(fixed=c(NA,0,1,NA)), type="binomial")
```

And this is the response I receive:

```
  could not find function "drm"
```

I understand that this may have to do with an issue installing the package properly. When I install the drc package using

`install.packages("drc")`

I get this, which seems fine:

```
trying URL 'https://cran.pacha.dev/bin/macosx/contrib/4.1/drc_3.0-1.tgz'
Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 923508 bytes (901 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 901 KB

tar: Failed to set default locale
```

But then when I retrieve it from the library through

`library(drc)`

It shows this message

```
 there is no package called 'haven'
```

How do I resolve this? Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue. Received on response on Reddit "You've gotten stuck in a dependency problem. Happens from time to time. If this was me, the next thing I'd do is `install.packages("haven")`, then try to load drc again. Keep repeating for every "there is no package" error until it works."